# ASP.NET MVC 6 - Browser getting closed when saving the content at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, c#-6.0

I am following the [Create a Web API in MVC 6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6).

If I am **saving** any file on the project *with/without* editing at run-time, the browser is getting closed. How to solve this issue?

Comment: this sounds like an IDE/debugger thing rather than MVC itself, no?

Comment: Yeah..It may be with `IDE/debugger` as you said..I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 CTP`. Version is `14.0.22609.0 D14REL`. Anyway on the final solution only, we can able to know about the source and cause of this issue.

Comment: When you say VS2015 CTP, is that the first CTP? Just to clarify, since there have been like six of them already.

Comment: I'm seeing this with VS15 CTP 6 too.

Answer (score 0):

The new edit & continue functionality for Roslyn currently does not work with the debugger attached.  This will be fixed in a future release.  You can start without debugging (ctrl + F5) if you want edit & continue support.

Comment: also CTRL+SHIFT+W (View in browser) if you want to keep the IIS Express open.